# How to avoid git rebase killing merge commits?

Tags: git, version-control, git-merge, git-rebase

Given the following `git` history:

```
    C-I    origin/master
   /
A-B-F-G-H  master
 \   /
  D-E      branch-b
```

I want to rebase my local `master` branch on top of `origin/master`, but I want to preserve the merge commit `G`. When I tried simply doing a `git rebase origin/master` while at `master` it squashed `D..E` as `G` and committed that with the commit message of `E`, so the history that there was a merge was lost. Is there some way of preserving this merge while still getting the rebase? For clarity, my intended result is:

```
A-B-C-I-F-G-H  master
 \       /
  D-----E      branch-b
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Add `--preserve-merges` to your rebase command. In case there were conflict resolutions in your merge, add 'recursive theirs' strategy as a parameter as well.

EDIT: `--preserve-merges` is now deprecated, use `--rebase-merges` instead

Comment: For absurd detail on what will happen with this flag, see also my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915430/what-exactly-does-gits-rebase-preserve-merges-do-and-why.

Comment: Can you elaborate why `recursive theirs` will help in this case? Merge commit `G` could have been created using a different conflict resolution strategy, could it not?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't going to be very pretty but I think you can do it.

Rebase F onto the origin/master as your new master branch:

```
git checkout F
git checkout -b new_master
git rebase origin/master
```

Merge branch-b into your new branch:

```
git merge branch-b
```

Cherry pick the remaining H commit onto your new master branch:

```
git cherry-pick master
```

Delete your old master branch:

```
git branch -D master
```

Unfortunately you will also have to do the merge again (hopefully it doesn't take any manual merging).

I didn't actually try this out, so I would make a backup of the repository first, but I am pretty confident that you will get what you want. I also suggest opening up gitk --all and refreshing the tree with "F5" after each command so you can see what is changing.

Someone else should still post if they know of a more elegant way to do it.