# Lost code after rebasing, in which merge is squashed

Tags: git, merge, rebase

This is my current structure (a `git log` but without the text), the feature branch is branched from `master`:

```
D  <- Keep this
C  <- Squash/meld everything before into this
*
ME <- Merge commit
|\
| B
* |
* |
|/
A  <- First commit of the feature branch
MA <- master
```

I want to keep the last commit of the current feature branch `D`, and squash/meld everything before it into the second last commit `C`, like this:

```
D
C' <- Squash everything before C and C itself
MA
```

I then do a rebase with `git rebase -i master`:

- The first commit `A` is kept, so I use `pick`. This will become `C'`.
- Everything between `A` and `C` is `squash`.

  I see no merge commit `ME`, but all other commits are listed. According to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6221624/5959593), merge commit will have everything in its branch, but with the message of `B`. `B` is listed, so this seems fine.
- The last commit `D` is kept, so `pick` again.

While rebasing, I see a lot of conflicts. After checking, all the conflicts are resolved by accepting "incoming changes", as it contains newer code.

However, after rebasing, the code no longer compiles, it is a mess now. I realize that the code in the merge commit `ME` is lost. `ME` is not a trivial merge, I have to resolve a lot of conflicts before merging.

I then tried to do a rebase in which I'll `pick` all the commits. I think it should proceed without any conflict, and leave the history intact (or recreating the exact same history). But git complains that there are conflicts, and the conflicts are exactly the same as the ones in the above interactive rebase session.

How should I do my rebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it :

- Run `git rebase -i HEAD~2`
- The sequencer script should mention `C` and `D`:

  Set `C` action to `edit`, save and close
- The rebase will apply `C` and pause.

  At this point, run `git reset --soft MA`, followed by `git commit` (this will squash `MA..C` in one single commit)
- Now proceed with the rebase: `git rebase --continue`

Comment: This is like a charm for me. I think I should pull updates from `master`, and resolve conflicts *before* merging next time.